# Multiple value in _.each()

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, clndr.js

So I want to apply two value from different iteratees (day.classes and event.part) on line 5. But it does not work, is my syntax wrong?

```
<div class="days">
  <div class="headers">
    <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %><div class="day-header"><%= day %></div><% }); %>
  </div>
  <% _.each([days, eventsThisMonth] function([day, event]) { %><div class="<%= day.classes %> <%= event.part %>" id="<%= day.id %>"><%= day.day %></div><% }); %>
</div>
<div class="events">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="x-button">✖</div>
    <div class="event-header">EVENTS</div>
  </div>
  <div class="events-list">
    <% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
      <div class="event">
        <a href="<%= event.url %>"><%= moment(event.date).format('MMMM Do') %>: <%= event.times %> <%= event.part %></a>
      </div>
    <% }); %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets from your callback function arguments on line 5 and it should work fine. The square brackets are converting your arguments into an array.

Change:

```
function([day, event])
```

To:

```
function(day, event)
```

Comment: I did that and no errors were shown in the console, but the calendar is still blank. Maybe you can have a look? https://announcer-squirrel-34686.netlify.com/